# About intersection of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Consider sets $A_1, A_2,  \ldots, A_n$. Let $A_i$ be a set of functions missing the element $i$ in their image. Turns out $\bigcap A_i$ is a set of functions missing $n$ elements in their image. Having some difficulty seeing that. For example, $\{(1, a), (2, a)\} \cap \{(1, b), (2, b)\} = \emptyset$ where the intersection of the given sets are not missing two elements. Can, someone, please, elaborate on this? Thanks.

Comment: Is $A_i$ a function or a set of functions ?

Comment: The set $\{(1,a),(2,a)\}$ is not a set of functions missing a specific element, is it?

Comment: If $A_i$ is the function, the specification means that there is no pair $(a,i)$ in $A_i$ for $a$ whatever. Thus $(a, 1) \notin A_1, (b, 2) \notin A_2$ and so on

Comment: $A_i$ is a set of functions.  $\{(1, a), (2, a)\}$ is a set of a single function whose image is missing $b$. I am considering $\{1, 2\} \to \{a, b\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is a triple $(X,Y,E)$ where $X$ is the domain, $Y$ the codomain and $E\subseteq X\times Y$ the association. When someone says $i$ is missed in the image, means that your function can be represented by the triple $(X,Y\setminus \{i\},E)$ because $E$ does not contain $(x,i)\in E.$
In this way, you seemed to be taking the intersection of the association $E$ of two different functions (i.e., $X$ and $Y$). Instead $A_i$ is the collection of sets you are describing with the common property that the codomain is $Y\setminus \{i\}$, so $X\in A_b$ and $Y\in A_a$ in your notation. $A_a\cap A_b=\emptyset$ if you are considering the codomains to be $\{a,b\}$ but $A_a = \{Y\}$ and $A_b=\{X\}$ so you have to be doing $\{X\}\cap \{Y\}$ which is different from taking $X\cap Y$ as you are suggesting.
**Edit/Example:**
Consider the functions from $f:\{1,2,3\}\longrightarrow \{a,b,c\}.$ I am going to drop the set notation and the tuples notation and denote, for example, the function $\{(1,a),(2,a)\}$ by $aa$ where the index is the preimage and the letter is the image at that index. So, for example
$$A_a=\{bbb,ccb,bcb,cbb,bbc,\color{red}{ccc},bcc,cbc\}$$ and $$A_b=\{aaa,cca,aca,caa,aac,\color{red}{ccc},acc,cac\},$$
so $A_a\cap A_b=\{\color{red}{ccc}\}=\{(1,c),(2,c),(3,c)\}.$
Notice that then $|A_a|=|A_b|=(3-1)^3$ and $|A_a\cap A_b|=(3-2)^3=1$

Comment: Can you an example with specific particular functions? Thanks.

Comment: @user847576 hope that example clarifies this.

Comment: Now I see 100%. Thanks.